# Gfci supplies a dock keeps tripping and can't be reset only replaced

Tags: gfci, protection

I have educated myself about gfci's although I am a diy'er. My gfci has my dock plugged into it. About once a year it trips and can't be reset only replaced. All outlets on the dock are weather proof. I am trying to find out if I need to rewire the dock or if the supply to the gfci can cause the tripping. This is a critical issue I need to resolve as I understand the implications of swimming near the dock if electrified. Again, I'm concerned that if I replace the dock wiring and the supply to the  gfci is causing the tripping then I have to replace the supply side, not an easy task.

Comment: I can't narrow down a specific circumstance that causes the tripping. One time I did hear the gfci sizzle when I flipped the switch to supply power to the gfci. Couldn't be reset only replaced.

Comment: Is this GFCI protected by some sort of weather proof cover in addition to being weatherproof itself?

Comment: Gfci is weather protected

Comment: I also installed a ground rod next to the gfci as well.

Comment: This is still a little vague-- the GFCI can (and needs to be) be rated as _Weather Resistant_. In addition to using a Weather Resistant GFCI, you need a good weatherproof cover installed to protect the GFCI.

Comment: Can't remember if gfci was weather proof but gfci is installed in a metal weatherproof box mounted about a foot above ground.

Comment: @TroySullivan, why the ground rod??? It is really serving no purpose at all in this installation.

Comment: I was informed by an electrician that it may cure the issue. It didn't.

Comment: The electrician inspected my wiring using a tester and came to the conclusion of installing the ground rod.

Comment: Bought a gfci breaker today and it's the wrong one. Have to return. Hoping that a gfci breaker will tell me something.

Comment: @Speedy Petey see above

Comment: @TroySullivan, your electrician was definitely wrong. It is extremely sad how misinformed some supposed professionals are on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that GFIs installed outdoors do not last nearly as long as indoors. Your issue is likely the constant proximity to water.

My suggestion is to install the GFI at a point in the circuit inside the house, or even install a GFI breaker.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! Will install a breaker and see what happens.

Comment: Can a gfci breaker be installed in my indoor breaker box?

Comment: @TroySullivan Yes, you'll install the GFCI breaker instead of the normal circuit breaker that is protecting this circuit.

Comment: My plan is to install a GFCI breaker on the line that runs to the dock and then I will add a switch at the dock that I can turn off and most of the time the switch will be off. if the GFCI breaker trips with the switch off then I know I have narrowed the problem down to something other than the dock. that's my plan

Comment: @TroySullivan, that is a good approach. Is the line dedicated to just the dock?

Comment: Yes and when I install the switch at the dock after having installed the gfci breaker in my indoor panel and then have the switch in the off position AND if the gfci breaker trips then I will have narrowed down the issue. Maybe just moving the gfci indoors will cure the issue.